# Where is the Java bug in my constructor code for this KnockKnockProtocol class?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm studying the following client/server code called [KnockKnockServer and KnockKnockClient.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)  It also has a helper class called [KnockKnockProtcol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockProtocol.java), which is responsible for the order of KnockKnock jokes.

I want to modify it so that you can start the program at a specific joke. As it is right now, you have to start with the first joke.

This is what tried for KnockKnockProtocol:

```
public class KnockKnockProtocol {

    int ourstep;

    public KnockKnockProtocol (int step) {
        this.ourstep = step;
    }

    private static final int WAITING = 0;
    private static final int SENTKNOCKKNOCK = 1;
    private static final int SENTCLUE = 2;
    private static final int ANOTHER = 3;

    private static final int NUMJOKES = 5;

    private int state = WAITING;
    int currentJoke = ourstep;  //we initialize the step here

    private String[] clues = { "Turnip", "Little Old Lady", "Atch", "Who", "Who" };
    private String[] answers = { "Turnip the heat, it's cold in here!",
                                 "I didn't know you could yodel!",
                                 "Bless you!",
                                 "Is there an owl in here?",
                                 "Is there an echo in here?" };

    public String processInput(String theInput) {
        String theOutput = null;

        if (state == WAITING) {
            theOutput = "Knock! Knock!";
            state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
        } else if (state == SENTKNOCKKNOCK) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Who's there?")) {
                theOutput = clues[currentJoke];
                state = SENTCLUE;
            } else {
                theOutput = "You're supposed to say \"Who's there?\"! " +
                "Try again. Knock! Knock!";
            }
        } else if (state == SENTCLUE) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase(clues[currentJoke] + " who?")) {
                theOutput = answers[currentJoke] + " Want another? (y/n)";
                state = ANOTHER;
            } else {
                theOutput = "You're supposed to say \"" + 
                clues[currentJoke] + 
                " who?\"" + 
                "! Try again. Knock! Knock!";
                state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
            }
        } else if (state == ANOTHER) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                theOutput = "Knock! Knock!";
                if (currentJoke == (NUMJOKES - 1))
                    currentJoke = 0;
                else
                    currentJoke++;
                state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
            } else {
                theOutput = "Bye.";
                state = WAITING;
            }
        }
        return theOutput;
    }
}
```

And in the Server class, I call the KnockKnockProtocol like this :

```
    /* omitting boilerplate code */
    String inputLine, outputLine;

    // Initiate conversation with client
    KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol(2);
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
    out.println(outputLine);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
        out.println(outputLine);
        if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
            break;
```

The problem is that , when I run my code I am always starting with the "Turnip" joke. How do I make it so that I can start at an arbitrary joke  within the list of jokes? I can see that the joke is controlled by the `clues` array, but after that I'm not seeing it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the input to the `KnockKnockProtocol` constructor, you will notice it directly affects the `currentJoke` counter via `this.ourstep` which is then used to reference the `clues` array.

Therefore to start at different locations you can pass in a different number in the constructor at the beginning of the program.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Are you sure this works? that code you reference is what I added on.. which did nt work

Comment: That could be because of where currentJoke is being set. Remove the step class variable and replace it with currentJoke. Set currentJoke inside the constructor and use it in your other function (making sure that you are using this.currentJoke). 

Only static elements like your arrays should be initialised outside of a constructor.